# How can one share content and users between two domains without using Domain module?

Tags: domain-access

We have DomainA and DomainB that we want to both redirect to the same Drupal site. Because we want to share content, users, and database.

The reason for this is because we are whitelisting our site to a client, the client can then see our site with a different front page, css styling overrides, and a different logo. Again it's the same site, using different colors and logo.

I found this Domain module here: https://www.drupal.org/project/domain

But since we are on hosted on Pantheon I was told by Pantheon they do not support this module so it does not work.

How should one approach this? We don't want visitors from DomainA to know DomainB exists and likewise.

Is it better to create a child theme that contains the new front page, css overrides, and logo and then we redirect to that path depending on URL? If so how can we do that without the Drupal module?

Thanks,

Comment: Ask Pantheon what it is about the domain module that they don’t support - that will either let you know if you can use the module anyway, because you only need the bots they do support, or let you know of alternative approaches that can’t be considered because they have the same non-support